# Strip first and last character from C string

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I have a C string that looks like `"Nmy stringP"`, where N and P can be any character. How can I edit it into `"my string"` in C?

Comment: Homework? Add the "homework" tag if it is.

Comment: No, not homework- just trying to learn C for fun.

Comment: In pure C there is no such thing as a "string".  Do you have a pointer to a buffer (`char *`) or a character array (`char[]`)?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To "remove" the 1st character point to the second character:

```
char mystr[] = "Nmy stringP";
char *p = mystr;
p++; /* 'N' is not in `p` */
```

To remove the last character replace it with a `'\0'`.

```
p[strlen(p)-1] = 0; /* 'P' is not in `p` (and it isn't in `mystr` either) */
```

Comment: This may not work because by initializing "Nmy stringP" as a literal, the compiler/linker can place it in read only memory, causing the edit to fail.

Comment: @Suppressingfire: "Nmy stringP" is indeed a literal string, but it is copied (char by char) to the array `mystr`. The array `mystr` is modifiable.

Comment: @pmg: Where are you copying?  `char *p = mystr` points `p` to `mystr`, it doesn't copy `mystr`.

Comment: @pmg: May I recommend `strdup`?

Comment: The literal string is copied to the location of the variable named "mystr". mystr is _not_ a pointer to the literal, it's a copy of the literal.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: `mystr` points to the literal array, but that array can be in read-only memory, no?

Comment: `strdup()` is not a Standard function. Its workings, on those implementations that offer it as an extension, may be different from implementation to implementation. I prefer to `malloc()` and `strcpy()` when needed. It wasn't needed to demonstrate how to remove the first and last chars of a string.

Comment: mystr is not a pointer, it is an array initialized with the contents of a string literal.  The code he has is correct.

Comment: char sz[] = "hello";
You will have sizeof(sz) == 6, NOT sizeof(sz) == 4.

Comment: @pmd: Re: `strdup` vs. `malloc` and `strcpy`: noted.

Comment: @pmd and others: What was confusing me is that pmd uses "copy".  What I assume you mean is that the string is laid out on the stack, not in static (possibly read-only) memory.  I had forgotten that.

Comment: @quark: doing `char arr[] = "hi";` is the same as `char arr[3]; arr[0] = 'h'; arr[1] = 'i'; arr[2] = '\0';`

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy: No mystr is not a pointer but it refers to the start of the array anyway. The issue isn't the size of the array (which the compiler can tell you, regardless of where the array was allocated), it was what kind of memory it was allocated it.

Comment: @pmd: Right.  I'm used to making string literals `const` and making them global, rather than making them local.  Local arrays go on the stack, and I'd forgotten that.  Sorry for the quibbling.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's global or not. `char arr[] = "foo";` copies the elements of the string literal (char by char: 'f', 'o', 'o', and '\0') to the array `arr`. It matters when you have pointers: `char *arr = "foo";` no copying here, whether it's a global or not.

Comment: Just thought I'd throw `char arr[] = { 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0' };` into the mix for good measure, kinda solidifies the initialization part. Thanks.

Comment: In the above question ,I think the following steps are missing ,
strcpy(myStr,p); , isn't it ? ...plz comment !

Comment: @CodeJack: no, nothing is missing. `mystr` is an array, and `p` points to somewhere in that array.

Comment: @pmg : Sir , but the first term of string `mystr` is still the same .
the string `mystr` is just `Nmy string` and the `p` is `my string`.
To change the actual string `mystr` , we need to use `strcpy(mystr,p)`

Comment: @CodeJack: ah! ok ... but you can't `strcpy()` between *things* that point within the same object. To change the contents of the array `mystr` you could use `memmove(mystr, mystr+1, sizeof mystr - 1);`

Answer (score 12):

Another option, again assuming that "edit" means you want to modify in place:

```
void topntail(char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    assert(len >= 2); // or whatever you want to do with short strings
    memmove(str, str+1, len-2);
    str[len-2] = 0;
}
```

This modifies the string in place, without generating a new address as pmg's solution does. Not that there's anything wrong with pmg's answer, but in some cases it's not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Further to @pmg's answer, note that you can do both operations in one statement:

```
char mystr[] = "Nmy stringP";
char *p = mystr;
p++[strlen(p)-1] = 0;
```

This will likely work as expected but behavior is undefined in C standard.

Comment: It's best though not to rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: @xav0989 Agreed, I intended to add that more as a comment (to highlight the reason not to do that), not as an alternative answer. I'm a bit new at this.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way:

```
//Note destroys the original string by removing it's last char
// Do not pass in a string literal.
char * getAllButFirstAndLast(char *input)
{
  int len = strlen(input); 
  if(len > 0)
    input++;//Go past the first char
  if(len > 1)
    input[len - 2] = '\0';//Replace the last char with a null termination
  return input;
}


//...
//Call it like so
char str[512];
strcpy(str, "hello world");
char *pMod = getAllButFirstAndLast(str);
```

The safest way:

```
void getAllButFirstAndLast(const char *input, char *output)
{
  int len = strlen(input);
  if(len > 0)
    strcpy(output, ++input);
  if(len > 1)
    output[len - 2] = '\0';
}


//...
//Call it like so
char mod[512];
getAllButFirstAndLast("hello world", mod);
```

The second way is less efficient but it is safer because you can pass in string literals into input.  You could also use strdup for the second way if you didn't want to implement it yourself.

Comment: The problem I see with your second implementation is that you need to make sure your output is large enough to handle the copy before you call getAllBufFirstAndLast(). In this case, I would recommend adding an outputLength variable to the call and let the called function manipulate output with strn* functions.

Comment: yes that's a precondition, yup you can add a length parameter.

Comment: 1) "The safest way:" would use `size_t len` rather than `int` 2) 2nd code assumes `output` has a size one more than needed.  E.g. `char mod[10];` would be UB.