# What does :-1 mean in python?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to port some Python code to C, but I came across this line and I can't figure out what it means:

```
if message.startswith('<stream:stream'):
    message = message[:-1] + ' />'
```

I understand that if '`message` starts with `<stream:stream` then something needs to be appended. However I can't seem to figure out where it should be appended. I have absolutely no idea what `:-1` indicates. I did several Google searches with no result.

Would somebody be so kind as to explain what this does?

Comment: -1 refers to the last element of `message`.

Comment: Just to be clear, message is a string with XML>

Comment: It chops the last character from `message`.

Comment: @poke: Not a duplicate question! If OP knew that this feature is called *The Python Slice Notation* he wouldn't need to ask the question

Comment: @GoranJovic The point is that that question explains the notation thoroughly.

Comment: @poke: And my point is that while they spawn the same answers the two questions are completely differently phrased. Hence, not duplicate questions - rather different questions with the same answer. Notice the word *exact* in the close vote dialog box?

Comment: @GoranJovic. Same answer, you say? So why split answers in two different places?

Comment: @GoranJovic Just so you know, I have brought this up on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164397/closing-question-as-exact-duplicate-when-title-contains-symbol

Comment: @poke: Oh, thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It is list indexing, it returns all elements `[:]` except the last one `-1`. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)

For example,

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> a[:-1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It works like this

`a[start:end]`

```
>>> a[1:2]
[2]
```

`a[start:]`

```
>>> a[1:]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

`a[:end]`
Your case

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> a[:-1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`a[:]`

```
>>> a[:]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 9):

It's called slicing, and it returns everything of `message` but the last element.

Best way to understand this is with example:

```
In [1]: [1, 2, 3, 4][:-1]
Out[1]: [1, 2, 3]
In [2]: "Hello"[:-1]
Out[2]: "Hell"
```

You can always replace `-1` with any number:

```
In [4]: "Hello World"[:2] # Indexes starting from 0
Out[4]: "He"
```

The last index is not included.

Answer (score 4):

It's called `slicing`

"Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by range(start, stop, step)."
-from this link: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice

You'll notice it's similar to the range arguments, and the `:` part returns the entire iterable, so the `-1` is everything except the last index.

Here is some basic functionality of slicing:

```
>>> s = 'Hello, World'
>>> s[:-1]
'Hello, Worl'
>>> s[:]
'Hello, World'
>>> s[1:]
'ello, World'
>>> s[5]
','
>>>
```

Follows these arguments:

```
a[start:stop:step]
```

Or

```
a[start:stop, i]
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns `message` without the last element. If `message` is a string, `message[:-1]` drops the last character.

See [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html).

Comment: How can this be easily ported to C ?

Comment: @user1663901 Change the last character before the null byte to a null byte itself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1726318/824544 `s[strlen(s)-1] = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your case directly:

```
if message.startswith('<stream:stream'): message = message[:-1] + ' />'
```

This basically checks, if `message` starts with `<stream:stream`, and if that is the case it will drop the last character and add a `' />'` instead.

So, as your message is an XML string, it will make the element an empty element, closing itself.