# strcpy () not working properly

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I am currently writing a program where i was stuck in a different kind of behaviour of strcpy() function . Here is short demo of it...

I went through the following question : [Strip first and last character from C string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726298/strip-first-and-last-character-from-c-string)

```
//This program checks whether strcpy() is needed or not after doing the modification in the string 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char mystr[] = "Nmy stringP";
        char *p = mystr ;
        p++;

        p[strlen(p)-1] = '\0';
        strcpy(mystr,p);
        printf("p : %s mystr: %s\n",p,mystr);

}
```

Output :-

```
p : y strnng mystr: my strnng
```

If i dont use strcpy() function , then i get

```
p : my string mystr : Nmy string
```

Why is this happening ??

Comment: I don't think you can use `strcpy` with overlapping source and destination.

Comment: You can't overlap memory for `strcpy()` source and target buffers. The behavior is undefined if you do so. See [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

Comment: general tip before you get in any deeper: never ever use strcpy. it's been the source of far too much bad code and far too many system vulnerabilities. `strncpy` is preferrable.

Comment: `memcpy()` is even more preferable, `memmove()` or overlaps. Either forces you to do what you end up always doing with `strncpy()` anyway: namely hard-terminate the destination buffer. `srtncpy()` is fine (I use it regularly), but knowing how it works (i.e. it *always* writes exactly `n` chars, and no more) is important.

Comment: @MarcB: strcpy isn't the source of system vulnerabilities; Poor system design is the source of system vulnerabilities... and `strncpy` isn't excluded from poor system design. Using `strncpy` can introduce a new class of vulnerabilities: Information disclosure due to lack of `'\0'` termination. Using strcpy in algorithms that are designed well isn't problematic at all.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: at least with strncpy, you don't have to HOPE for a null terminator. you might still trash something, but only up to `n` bytes worth, rather than the 0->MAX_INT range possible with strcpy

Comment: @MarcB strncpy doesn't necessarily produce strings, which is where the problem with your advice lies. Don't convince people that it does. You can't give a definition to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Sir , as per documentation , `strncpy` still gives undefined behaviour  when overlapping objects , hence this would also not solve the issue...i think ..

Comment: @Marc: strncpy is in no way preferable. strncpy is a death trap. If there is not enough space, it will produce a result that isn't a valid string. When copying UTF-8 strings, which is a huge percentage of the use cases for large strings, it can produce invalid results. There is strlcpy, but the best way is to have code that just allocates enough memory for the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard says:

> 7.24.2.3
>
> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
>   undefined.

You could use `memmove` or a different method altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `strcpy` with overlapping memory locations i.e., if source and destination strings overlap. In this case, the behavior is undefined as stated in the standards.

But you can use a `temp` memory location to do the swap like [this](http://codepad.org/gJiZgoyV)