# Setting last character in a string to 0 causes program crash

Tags: c

This is for a homework assignment, so it can not use loops of any kind as a way to force recursion practice. I am also not to change the method signature, or anything in the `main()` function.

The function is intended to use recursion to print a string in reverse. I learned on this site ([Strip first and last character from C string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726298/strip-first-and-last-character-from-c-string)) how to remove the last character in a string. When I try and reproduce it in my code, the program crashes on execution. Here is that code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_reverse_str(char *str) {
    if (strlen(str) == 1) 
        printf("%c", &str[0]);
    else {
        int len = strlen(str);
        int lastIndex = len - 1;
        char endChar = str[lastIndex];
        printf("%c", &endChar);
        str[lastIndex] = 0;
        print_reverse_str(str);
    }
}

int main() {
    print_reverse_str("My string");
    printf("\n");
    print_reverse_str("!ti tog uoy ,siht daer nac uoy fI");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You're trying to modify a string literal.

Comment: `printf` `%c` takes a `char`, not a pointer to a `char`.

Comment: `strlen` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Comment: You don't need to modify a string to print it in reverse.

Comment: Your code doesn't handle empty strings correctly.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for your prompt feedback. I should have mentioned, the assignment requires no error checking, it is assumed the code is being made only for the presented problem.

Comment: Er, OK? What does that have to do with any of my comments?

Comment: @melpomene "Your code doesn't handle empty strings correctly." Despite the fact that it would produce more complete (and therefore better) code, empty strings can be left out of consideration for the purposes of the assignment.

Comment: Handling empty strings correctly would make the code shorter and simpler (... as demonstrated by @BLUEPIXY's answer).

Comment: @melpomene I see that now. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can not change a string literal.
2. Character display with `printf`. E.g `printf("%c", character);`, not &character

try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_reverse_str(char *str){
    if (*str){
        print_reverse_str(str+1);
        printf("%c", *str);
    }
}

int main(){
    print_reverse_str("My string");
    printf("\n");
    print_reverse_str("!ti tog uoy ,siht daer nac uoy fI");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: That's got it! Thank you kindly :)