# How to store the name of the running C program?

Tags: c, argv

I don't want to encrypt my running program.
So I need to get the name of this one.

Already I'm trying with argv[0] -> looks like "./main".
I need to cut the "." from it.
Tried with:

```
char exec_path[PATH_MAX];
for(int i=1; executableName[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        exec_path[i-1]=executableName[i];
    }
snprintf(exec_path, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", name, exec_path);
```

but it returns too many errors and I think there is another nice solution. (maybe a lib?)

Basically, just by adding my argv[0] to the running path, I get this. U can see the problem.
[image: U can see the problem here]

EDIT:

Thanks to all answer, it worked with

```
memcpy(str, executableName+2, sizeof(executableName));
    snprintf(exec_path, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", name, str);
```

Comment: You aren't appending the terminating `nul` character to your `exec_path` string. But `strcpy(exec_path, executableName+1)` is likely simpler.

Comment: The `argv[0]` gimmick is just that: a gimmick (which will not work under many circumstances). Nevertheless there is no better way :-) Try `strcpy(yourstring, argv[0] + 2);`

Comment: @pmg Or `memmove` within `argv[0]` - doing so is actually well-defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strip first and last character from C string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726298/strip-first-and-last-character-from-c-string)

Comment: You don't need to cut the `"./"` part. Even Windows is happy with a path that has single dots in it, and ignores them happily. Just append `argv[0]` to the leading path and don't forget the path separator. Please be aware that `argv[0]` could be an absolute path, but then your solution will not work, either.

Comment: Consider whether POSIX function [`basename()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html)
can help you.  It returns the last component of a path.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
char* str = argv[0] + 1;
```

Comment: I think that solution should be more general, it means it should work for every type of path. Example: `../main`

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ans;
for (int i = strlen(argv[0]); i >=0; i--)
{
    if (argv[0][i] == '/')
    {
        ans = argv[0][i]+1;
        break;
    }    

}
```